# Why behavioral strategies and sequence form do not work with imperfect recall games?

Tags: algorithms, game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

The behavioural strategies assign, independently for each information set, a probability distribution over actions.

The sequence form game is a game representation that, given a node W, a sequence q of player i is the ordered set of actions of player i appearing in the path from the root of the game tree to W.
The strategy that you can define on the sequence form is called realization strategy.

I would like to have some intuitive explanation of why these kind of strategies and game representations are ill-defined in the imperfect recall set up.

Comment: You'll have to define all those terms, so we know what you are talking about.

Comment: I edited the post. I hope is clearer now, sorry for the missing information